# Nginx host not found in upstream, Docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

*I acknowledge this question has been asked several times, however none of the solutions that I looked at worked for me*

I have a nuxt application which I'm trying to run on multiple instances and load balance with nginx.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services: 

    web:
        image: nodeapp
        ports: 
            - "3005:3005"
        networks:
            - backend


    db: 
        image: "mongo"
        volumes:
            - "/dockerdata:/data/db"
        ports: 
            - "27017:27017"
        networks:
            - backend
    redis: 
        image: "redis"
        ports: 
            - "6379:6379"
        networks:
            - backend
    nginx: 
        image: nginx-nodeapp
        links: 
            - web:web
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        depends_on: 
            - web
networks:
    backend:
        driver: "bridge"
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream containers {
    server web:3005;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://containers
    }
}
```

When accessing local host I receive the following error:
**host not found in upstream "web:3005" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2**

Comment: `web` and `nginx` services need to share at least one common network. `nginx` is only on default and does now use `backend`.

Comment: So nginx needs to also be on the "backend" network?

Comment: .. or any other network it shares with `web`. You can make a special one for that if you wish. `backend` will do. As is, your `nginx` container is actually isolated, alone on the `default` network and cannot communicate with any other service.

Comment: when I add the backend network to the nginx service, connection gets refused.

Comment: connections to what from what ? With what exact message ? With what logs on the relevant container(s) ?... Please edit your question.

Comment: Apologies - There are no container logs. Now that I've added the backend network, when I try to access localhost:80, the request simply times out.
https://prnt.sc/12ncelb

Comment: How about changing `server web:3005;` to `server web;` in the upstream?